# How to deploy Visual Studio Cordova app to Windows 8?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

When I create a sample cordova app in Visual Studio I can target Android and it generates an APK what I can open easily in Android. How to do the same for Windows 8/8.1 ? ... what is the equivalent of the APK file for windows? (I was looking for a .exe or similar but cant find ... assume this must be simple!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 8.0/8.1 ***.appx*** and **.appxupload** package are created after build and like apk this is also a zip file, to view the content of package, change the extension to .zip and extract the content. *.appx is equivalent to apk in Windows.
Appx package after build is located at bld[Debug or Release]\platforms\Windows\AppPackages

Comment: Am new to windows platform, when using android the apk file is installed directly via click but am having a windows tablet and when i click on the appx package i dont get the installation screen

Answer (score 0):

qtime67,

Here's a link to the Cordova documentation on how to package an app for windows 8/8.1.

***Documentation***
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn757048.aspx

The documentation does the job, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below link for a detailed explanation on how to make the Cordova Windows/Windows Phone apps ready for packaging:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#windows-81

From Visual Studio, you basically do a Project --> Store --> Create App Packages, in the resulting Wizard, choose 'No' if you just want to create the equivalent of apk and test it on a phone/emulator and click next. Choose Version and other details and click on 'Create'. This should generate an 'appxupload' file which you can move to a phone and install and test.