# Cordova Visual Studio, install appx on windows tablet

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, appx

I´ve developed an cordova app with visual studio an deployed it to windows.

After that I get a folder "~\platforms\windows\AppPackages\" with a *.appx file like in the description of the answer in 
[How to deploy Visual Studio Cordova app to Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014771/how-to-deploy-visual-studio-cordova-app-to-windows-8)

I copied the appx file on my windows tablet with an usb-stick. Now I tried to run the file.
--> Same reaction like on a normal desktop pc. Can´t run the extension.
(Dialog with "How should this type of file to be opened")

What is the right way, without an app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy for testing purposes, under the AppPackages folder you should see a *_Test folder as shown below.  You can copy this folder onto the machine you want to test the app on.  Within that folder there is a powershell script that will install the app onto the machine.

[image: Contents of AppPackages folder]

Comment: Thank you. It works.

I want to install the app on a few device permanently.
Is this the best way for it? (Without app store)