# Install windows app without store

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-build, windows

I´ve developed a windows app with cordova/phonegap in visual studio.

I installed it for testing purposes with that instruction:
[Cordova Visual Studio, install appx on windows tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325937/cordova-visual-studio-install-appx-on-windows-tablet)

Now, I want to install it on a few devices (Around 10) without publishing the app in the windows store.

With this instruction, I need a developer licence on each device. (and it is limited in time too)

Is there an other opportunity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to perform bate app test. But you still need to publish it to the windows Dev center as described in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832612.aspx).

For enterprise LOB apps, we can test it using [Developer sideloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx). But just as you've noticed, it requires developer licence on test device.