# Install appx app on windows tablet permanently without app store

Tags: windows, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, appx

On the basis of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325937/cordova-visual-studio-install-appx-on-windows-tablet), I installed the visual studio cordova app on my windows tablet.

I want to install the app on a few device permanently. 
Is this the best way for it? (Without app store)
And with this way, I have to use a license which have a expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For test purpose, I think it's better to use developer sideloading, which is introduced in [Developer sideloading Windows Store a](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn832613.aspx)pps.

And the developer sdeloadig app dosn't expire.