# Cordova Windows using custom certificate

Tags: excel, visual-studio, cordova

I have a Cordova app and I want to create an appx package to publish it. Mainly, the app generates Excel files and it works well.

The thing is, once I specify my custom certificate in the `package.windows.appxmanifest` file and I run the app (in Debug or Release mode in VS) my generated files are corrupted. I get the same behavior on a device. Also, I am able to generate the APPX even though it is generating corrupted files.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you please give more details? How are you running, with `Visual Studio` or with `Cordova CLI`? What exactly is corrupted?

Comment: Which VS version do you use?

Comment: Running `cordova build -- --archs="x86"`
Using VS 13 and Codova 4.3.1

Comment: I tried upgrading VS and Cordova without success.

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30325937/cordova-visual-studio-install-appx-on-windows-tablet ?